# Error in method invocation when executing java scripts in selenium using jmeter

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, htmlunit-driver

I'm getting following error while try to execute the java script within my selenium code.

Error: 
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver' : at Line: 47 : in file: inline evaluation of:`import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' : executor .executeScript ( "document.getElementById('icon-2')[0].click()" ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.By; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org. . . . '' at line number 47

Response headers:

Code:

```
public HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME,true);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
driver.get(appURL);
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('icon-2')[0].click()");
```

How do I execute the java script within selenium?

Page dom structure :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Beanshell interpreter doesn't support [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) therefore your attempt to call [executeScript() method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) whose 2nd parameter is `java.lang.Object... args` is failing.

The easiest solution is switching to Groovy language as:

1. [It is recommended by JMeter developers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. Groovy supports all modern JDK features and has its own [syntax sugar](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top
3. [Groovy performs much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)